# Why does the "skippable" state change depending on the order of the Composable arguments?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When defining a Composable that accepts interface as an argument, the "skippable" status of the Composable changed depending on the order in which the arguments are defined. I do not understand why this would result.

Compose Compiler Version : 1.4.3

### Case1

When the argument is "interface" only, this Composable is SKIPPABLE. And there is no notation "stable"!

```kotlin
interface HogeRepository {
    fun hoge()
    fun hoge2()
}
@Composable
fun MainScreen(illustRepository: IllustRepository)
```

Compose Compiler Reports

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun MainScreen(
  illustRepository: IllustRepository
)
```

### Case2

When stable parameters other than "interface" are added, this Composable is no longer SKIPPABLE.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    illustRepository: IllustRepository,
    name: String
)
```

Compose Compiler Reports

```
restartable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun MainScreen(
  unstable illustRepository: IllustRepository
  stable name: String
)
```

### Case3

When the "interface" parameter is defined last, this Composable is SKIPPABLE. And the "interface" is no notation "stable"!

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    name: String,
    illustRepository: IllustRepository
)
```

Compose Compiler Reports

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun MainScreen(
  stable name: String
  illustRepository: IllustRepository
)
```

How do these differences occur?

I would have expected these Composable to be "non skippable" regardless of the order of the arguments.